# Procedure or Function has too many arguments specified in ASP.NET using VB.NEt

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Every time I run my update function I generate a Procedure or Function has too many arguments specified error and I think I have been looking at this for too long because I can't find the root cause. Any guidance would be appreciated.

My VB.NET code is as follows:

```
    Public Function UpdateGenInfo_E1_01_02(ByVal pstrCon As String, _
                                     ByVal appNo As String, _
                                     ByVal revNo As String, _
                                     ByVal prName As String, _
                                     ByVal prAddr As String, _
                                     ByVal prAddr2 As String, _
                                     ByVal prCity As String, _
                                     ByVal prState As String, _
                                     ByVal prZip As String) As Integer
    Try


        'Create parameter
        Dim lsqlParams(8) As SqlParameter
        'fill parameter

        lsqlParams(0) = New SqlParameter("@AppNo", appNo)
        lsqlParams(1) = New SqlParameter("@RevNo", revNo)
        lsqlParams(2) = New SqlParameter("@PrName", prName)
        lsqlParams(3) = New SqlParameter("@PrAddr", prAddr)
        lsqlParams(4) = New SqlParameter("@PrAddr2", prAddr)
        lsqlParams(5) = New SqlParameter("@PrCity", prCity)
        lsqlParams(6) = New SqlParameter("@PrState", prState)
        lsqlParams(7) = New SqlParameter("@PrZip", prZip)
        'Return dataset
        Return SqlHelper.ExecuteNonQuery(pstrCon, CommandType.StoredProcedure, "up_UpdateGenInfo_E1_01_02", lsqlParams)
    Catch ex As Exception
        'Throw error

        Throw ex
    End Try
End Function
```

My Stored Procedure is as follows:

```
USE [EpUpdates]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[up_UpdateGenInfo_E1_01_02]    Script Date: 04/26/2013 12:00:24 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS OFF
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[up_UpdateGenInfo_E1_01_02] 
(

   @AppNo varchar(10),
   @RevNo varchar(4),
   @PrName varchar(10),
   @PrAddr varchar(50),
   @PrAddr2 varchar(50),
   @PrCity varchar(30),
   @PrState varchar(2),
   @PrZip varchar(10)
)
AS
   UPDATE EpUpdates.dbo.GenInfo_E1_01_02
   SET    PrName=@PrName,
          PrAddr=@PrAddr,
          PrAddr2= @PrAddr2,
          PrCity=@PrCity,
          PrState=@PrState,
          PrZip=@PrZip  
   WHERE (AppNo = @AppNo) 
     AND (RevNo = @RevNo)
```

Comment: I assume `("@PrAddr2", prAddr)` is just a typo, and it's not likely to be your real problem.

Answer (score 2):

You have a C# Style array length specifier in a VB Program.

```
Dim lsqlParams(8) As SqlParameter     ' in C# this would create a length of 8 items.
                 ' in VB this creaes 9 items! (the upper bound of array)
```

Your error is the extra empty array element. 
change to a (7).

To avoid this kind of error I usually use a list to accmulate items (dont like setting the array numbers)

```
Dim lsqlParams as new List(of SqlParameter)
lsqlParams.add(New SqlParameter(blah...))
' then pass to routine via ...
lsqlParams.ToArray
```

Comment: I changed the array length from 8 to 7, but I am still generating the same error.

Comment: The exact error I am receiving is up_UpdateGenInfo_E1_01_02 has too many arguments specified. I also tried using your other method using a list, but didn't have much luck.

Comment: I don't use that SqlHelper Wrapper class. Are you sure you don't need to specify the Parameters in the SQL Itself? "up_UpdateGenInfo_E1_01_02" --> "up_UpdateGenInfo_E1_01_02 (at)AppNo, (at)RevNo ...."

Comment: In the above the (at) is the At Symbol... just to be clear, it would not allow me to post the comment with the At Symbols :)

Comment: I just took a look at the SQL table my stored procedure and code is querying and I realized that there are actually 9 columns in the database and not 8. Would leaving this column out of the stored procedure and code cause this issue? the column allows nulls.

Comment: If your doing an UPDATE inside the Procedure I dont see how that could be the problem. It simply wouldn't update the missing field. It still sounds like a mismatch between the procedure arguments and the SQL executed behind the scenes in ".ExecuteNonQuery". Do you have 2 databases? (Possibly running against Staging instead of Development, which may have different SQL Definition?). Possibly try executing the procedure manually in TSQL with the same parameters to ensure it does actually work.